# setting target for a UIButton which was made in IB

Tags: interface-builder, uibutton, target

I have a UIView with a bunch of buttons in it (something like 200 of them)...

The view was set up in IB so I would have to manually wire every button with a single handler...

I'm trying to traverse the subviews of the view, looking for buttons and then set the button's target programmatically... which results in a crash (I get the compile warning «UIButton may not respond to addTarget...»).

this is the loop:

```
for(UIButton *aButton in self.view.subviews){

        if([aButton isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]){

            [aButton addTarget:self selector:@selector(buttonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        }
    }
```

I can access some of the properties of the button, like visibility and title... but not the action?

Any help greatly appreciated...!

Answer (score 5):

wow - it was actually pretty simple - the guys over at devforums.apple.com gave me the hint...

```
for(UIButton *aButton in self.view.subviews){

        if([aButton isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]){

            [aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        }
    }
```

Can you spot the difference? ;)

Comment: I spent fifteen minutes on this, but I found it!  addTarget:action:forControlEvents instead of addTarget:selector:forControlEvents.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `respondsTo` or some other variant to avoid getting the error. This would ensure you can set the action for `aButton`.

However, if you are looping over all these buttons anyway, why not just build them programmatically? Are they design heavy?

Comment: Yep - they are VERY design heavy. They're overlay-buttons for a map and the indicate spots on this map (whithout having the geocode for that spot). So placing them in IB is very handy - building them programmatically would be a pain :)

can you give me a hint how this «respondsTo»-thingy would be implemented? all I found so far was `respondsToSelector:@selector(`...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Fair enough. I imagine you would want to test something like `[aButton respondsToSelector:@selector(addTarget) ...]`

Comment: Well - thanks for the hint for using this. Although, it doesn't solve my problem. The error goes away, but the targetAction isn't applied to the button... Seems like I have to do this in IB :(

Answer (score 0):

you should mark your answer as correct.

But just in case anybody else comes:

*It should be:*

addTarget:self **action**:@selector(buttonClick:)

instead of:

addTarget:self **selector**:@selector(buttonClick:)